# My system won't come on after upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to 18

Tags: 18.04

I just updated from Ubuntu 16 to 18. While it was going on I fell asleep and woke up to find that during or before searching for obsolete files my internet got interrupted.
I tried to reconnect but it didn't. but because it was already searching for obsolete files and had already downloaded and installed the updates I figured restarting wouldn't be damaging to the process. Now after rebooting it won't come on it keeps blinking on and off and showing me a terminal screen which I don't understand with some errors. I'm quite new to Linux any help on how to make it come on will be appreciated. I tried to add a picture of the screen but I can't

Comment: There's nowhere indicating the addition...

Comment: I'm sorry about that I tried to add a picture but I need 10 reputation to do that

Comment: On the screen it's starting some modules and mounting but there are like three errors

Comment: On the screen it's starting some modules and mounting but there are like three errors. The first says- ACPI Error: Region embeddedControl(ID=3)has no handler. while the second error says- ACPI Error:Method parse/execution failed. And the last line says something like- ERROR notify_scan_status: ice........ before the ppp link was shut down. I apologise if it's scattered but this is the best way I can explain what the screen is displaying.